Is there a way to get the coveo translated field name for a given template's field using API?
I am trying to use rest api /coveo/rest/search/v2/values, which requires the field, the fieldname looks like @ffacilitytype61595, since each developer machine and different environment is tied to different coveo instance, so each instance could have different field name, but I know the template name and the field name, is there a way to get the translated field name either using api or SDK?
In my coveo instance, there are multiple fields created for the full name, each with different number suffix for different index, as shown in the following screenshot. also, the same field and same index on my another Sitecore instance, the number is different. How do those numbers got generated? How do I get that number by given template and field name?



When you indicating translated value do you want the different languages content?

I only have English version. but I do not know that XXXX for each environment - I want to find that XXXX

Basically, if you need content with a translated version, you need to specify the language version in the query. I am sharing the query for Coveo where you can refer to an example of a translated version.
In the query below, flanguageXXXXX is specified, which will bring the required translated content.
{
        "aq": "(@ftemplatenameXXXXX=='Product')(@flanguageXXXXX==en)(@fproductidXXXXX==TTT.TEST.XXXXX)",
        "fieldsToInclude": [
            "fproductidXXXXX",
            "fnamevaluesXXXXX",
            "fgacategoryXXXXX"
        ],
        "numberOfResults": 5,
        "maximumAge": -1
    }


where do I get the XXXX?

This is the hash value of your coveo account, I put XXXX because I can display in public as it's for account specific

Thanks! how do I calculate the hash value? from what input? secondly, if those number are tied to my account, why I have fields with different XXXX?

Yes, with your coveo account there should be Hash value which will be account specific and non need to calculate just go to account and browse.

from https://platform.cloud.coveo.com/admin? or from sitecore/l/coveo/command-center/? can you tell me how to browse?

https://platform.cloud.coveo.com/admin                                                                                     Bascially When you create Coveo Index then you will see hash value also you can see by browsing the item in Coveo Cloud account.

sorry I could not find how
